# RecyclerView in a ViewFlipper

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, viewflipper

I am implementing a RecycerView. I would like all the contents of the Recyclerview to be stack on each other and flip between them using a Viewflipper. It seems none of the available LayoutManagers support this.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

```
<ViewFlipper
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dictFlipper"
        android:autoStart="true"
        android:flipInterval="8000">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dictionary_view"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </ViewFlipper>
```